# How to perform left outer join with distinct clause

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following data:

**Users**:

```
Id  UserId  Name
----------------
1   1       Him
2   10      Her
3   2       Other
```

**Groups**:

```
Id  GroupId  UserId
-------------------
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        10
```

In SQL I can do something like this to determine if a user is in any group

```
select * 
from Users as u
left outer join (select distinct(UserId) from Groups) as g on u.UserId = g.UserId
```

The result should be something like this.

```
Id  UserId  Name  UserId
------------------------
1   1       Him   1
2   10      Her   10
3   2       Other Null
```

But how can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: a "UserId" is commonly inherently a distinct value, you might not even need the distinct clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this one is helpful for u,

```
var data = (from u in Users
                    join g in Groups.Where(a => a.UserId == (from gp in  Groups.Select(r=>r.UserId).Distinct() ) )
                   on u.UserId equals g.UserId into outer 
                   from x in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select u);
```

Answer (score 0):

In function syntax, it would look like

```
var result = Users.Join(Groups, 
    U => U.UserId, G => G.GroupId, 
    (U,R) => R.Select(
        G => new { Id = U.Id, UserId = U.UserId, Name = U.Name, UserId = G.UserId }
        ).DefaultIfEmpty(new { Id = U.Id, UserId = U.UserId, Name = U.Name, UserId = null })
    );
```